# when clean and build project getting error in eclipse console

Tags: android, eclipse

When clean and build project getting error in eclipse console. And one more thing `R.java in not be created it show error on R`.

Error are like

`W/ResourceType( 7964): Bad XML block: header size 85 or total size 5529592 is larger than data size 0`.

Any help guys why this happened?

I am using these two xml

itemlist.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNewsSource"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#64CBD8" />
```

and secone one main.xml

```
<com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/scrollView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Prev" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" />
```

Comment: plz go to error log and post that error

Comment: @sam we are not able to run on emulator then how to get the logcat. Its open first console

Comment: check your resource xml.. in one/some of them there are some problems

Comment: i'm not talkin abt runnig..just window-->show view-->error_log ..then post d error ..

Comment: Are you using any external library? like https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Android-HorizontalScrollView ??

Comment: ya right please check this

Comment: plz post all code in ur xml file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Copy "android-support-v4.jar" from your main project libs and paste it in your all external libraries.(Mean replace all android-support-v4.jar with you main one support library.)
2. Ensure that there is no duplication of xml data (let say:same code in your external library string file and in your main project's string file.)
3. Remove all external libraries, Clean+build your project.
4. Again include your external libraries one by one and clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
"W/ResourceType( 8032): Bad XML block: header size 85 or total size 5529592 is larger than data size 0"
```

Means that you have a malformed XML resource.

You need to solve the XML error then you clean build your project.

Please validate your [XML online](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: is this you complete `XML` file?

Answer (score 0):

First Clean project from project menu
Then fix import in in your class file like this:

import com.your.package.xyz.R;